# How to get the difference between barcode scanner pause event and the ionicPlatform pause event?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, barcode-scanner, pause

I am developing an app using Ionic 1.3/Cordova/phonegap  where the user should not leave the app, if he do so , he will be redirected back to the first page to login, and his session will end.

The Cordova plugin I am using is :

phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 5.0.0 "BarcodeScanner"

For pausing and resuming I am using $ionicPlatform.on():

```
$ionicPlatform.on('pause', function(){
// something
  }); 

$ionicPlatform.on('resume', function(){
// something
       });
```

On android 4.x and newer, the barcode scanner plugin uses a pause event to pause the app and save energy and the lunch the camera to scan, and then resume to get the result.

How would I know the normal pause event( switching to other app, or click home button) from the barcode scanner pause event ?

I have used true false switch. $scope.scanner = true; I set it true from inside barcode scanner function and pass it to the pause event. On resume it will check if the $scope.scanner == true or false to redirect the user.

The problem is it only works the first time. If I click scan button, then get the result, it would not redirect the user. Then if I pause the app manually by clicking home button, it will redirect the user to first page on resume. And then, After the user log in again this method would not work anymore. It will redirect the user to first page anyway whether he clicked on scan button and or click home button. As far as I know it is because the resume event fires before the barcode scanner resume event on the second time.

This only happens on Android.

Snippet of my code:

```
$ionicPlatform.on('pause', function(){
$scope.scanner = $scope.scanner || false;

});

$ionicPlatform.on('resume', function(){

if($scope.scanner === false){
$state.go('firstpage');
}
});

//scan function
$scope.scan = function(){ $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then(function(result){

if(result.text.length){
$scope.scanner = true;
// do some work
}
else{
$scope.scanner = true;
// do some work
}
}, function(error){
$scope.scanner = true;
console.log(error)
})
}
```

Comment: I have switched to time span between the pause event and the resume event to control this. If the time is grater than 1 minute the user probably taking a break so it will redirect the user to first page. It is a temporary solution. But, I hope I can figure this out and or get some help.